# Numbers similar to Fermat Numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

There is much to know about the Fermat numbers. Now I propose the numbers of the form $f = 2^{2^n} +2^j +1 $. Of course if $j$ is even, then $ 3 | f$. Also, If $ n = 1, j = 1 $, then $ f = $ 7. If $ n = 2, j = 1 $, then $ f = 19 $. If $ n = 4, j = 1 $, then $ f = $ 65539, i.e.  they are twin Fermat primes.
The question is, we can say that $ f = 2^{2^n} +2^j +1 $ with $ n> 4 $ and $ 1 \leq j <2^n$ is composite? I have found it  is true up to n = 15.  Some one know anything else?

Comment: Was there any noticeable pattern in the factors of $f$ for $n>4$?

Comment: $f=(2^{2^n}-1)+(2)(2^{j-1}+1)$, and the first summand is divisible by $2^{2^r}+1$ for all $r\lt n$, so it suffices to prove that $2^{2^r}+1$ divides $2^{j-1}+1$ for some $r$. 

Comment: And that's easy, since $2^{j-1}=2^{q2^r}$ for some $r$ and some odd $q$. 

Comment: @Gerry: I don't believe your reasoning covers the case $j=1$.  (It is by no coincidence that all of the OP's examples are when $j=1$)

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $2^{2^n}+3$ is divisible by $7$.